# PHP background sync using http requests

Tags: php, multithreading, curl, multitasking

I have a php coded that is suppose to sync data from thousands of http links every 2 minutes and update the database.

However, some of the websites are too slow, and my current approach which is using foreach and going over the links one by one takes around 15 minutes.

Is there a better way to achieve this task in a shorter time?

```
foreach($email as $emails) {

imap_open(......);

// update db

}
```

Thanks

Comment: something like `curl_multi_init()` or RollingCurl ?

Comment: for some of the requests, I'm using imap_open

Comment: I think we need a bit more explanation of *why* you're using imap.

Comment: to sync emails, with a local db

Answer (score 0):

Without sample code it's difficult to advise. However it may be that you are using a connection method which 'blocks' until the response is received. This means PHP stops until that request has completed one at a time.

What you need is to connect to multiple systems at once and poll for responses.

fsockopen() can do this, if you set  stream_set_blocking() on the socket before writing the http request headers. Then fread can

An alternate solution would be to fork the PHP into many processes each requesting a different source.

Is that enough to point you in the right direction? If not please include some sample code so we know what methods you currently use and somebody may expand it to do what you require.

Comment: the code consists of curl and imap_open functions inside foreach, I'll update the answer with a sample. imap_open doesn't seem to seupport stream_set_blocking.

Comment: Great, so for the imap_open requests. Have you considered forking the process. This would create a new php thread for each lookup and not hold  up the scan. 

A very basic example would look like:
`foreach($targets as $target) {`
 `$pid = pcntl_fork();`
 `if ($pid < 0) {`
     `die(' Couldn't fork');`
 `} elseif ($pid) {`
     `// we are the parent, move on`
     `continue;`
 `} else {`
     `// we are the child, make our remote request and exit`
     `$doRemoteLookupAndUpdateDb($target);`
     `exit();`
 `}`
`}`
In real terms you probably need a rate limiting mechanism and more feedback

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do them in parallel.

One solution would be plit the current list of URLs across say 20 threads. You've not shown us your code, but imagining it currently does something like this:

```
$urls=mysqli_query($link,
      "SELECT url FROM list");
while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($urls)) {
    ...
```

You might try something like the following to shard the data set:

```
$instance=(integer)$argv[1];
if (0==$instance) {
    die("Next time start me with a number between 1 and 20 indicating the thread");
}
$urls=mysqli_query($link,
      "SELECT url FROM list WHERE $instance-1 = CONVERT(
         CONV(SUBSTR(MD5(url),4), 16, 10) USING SIGNED INTEGER)
       ) % 20
      ");
```

Alternatively you could batch up the HTTP requests in a single PHP thread and call them cuncurrently using [curl_multi_exec](http://lampe2e.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/making-stuff-faster-with-curlmultiexec.html)